# Print a list of all fonts used in all documents in a directory

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, microsoft-word, fonts, powershell

Suppose you have a directory which contains (perhaps in sub-directories) Word 2000 (.doc) files.

Now I want to analyze which fonts are actually used by a specific user. So, how can I scan this directory and get automatically a list of all fonts used in all documents.

For example if in document1 the fonts font2 and font4 and in document2 the fonts font1 and font4 are used, it should print:

```
font1
font2
font4
```

A statistics of how often a font is used is not needed (but nice to have).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to look inside a Word document from PowerShell would probably be to use COM automation. This tutorial looks good: [Learn Powershell: Beginning with PowerShell and Word](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/12/31/beginning-with-powershell-and-word/).

You could then do a Google search for VBA macros that create a list of fonts, and translate that to PowerShell.

Also see this question: [List fonts used by a Word Document (faster method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261108/list-fonts-used-by-a-word-document-faster-method).